# What is the difference between .HLSL and .VS and .PS code for DirectX11?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, directx, directx-11

I am following Rastertek tutorials, http://www.rastertek.com/dx11s2tut04.html

In this code the shaders are compiled from *.vs and *.ps files

```
result = D3DCompileFromFile("light.vs", NULL, NULL, "LightVertexShader", "vs_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, NULL, &vertexShaderBuffer, &errorMessage);

result = D3DCompileFromFile("light.ps", NULL, NULL, "LightPixelShader", "ps_5_0", D3D10_SHADER_ENABLE_STRICTNESS, NULL, &pixelShaderBuffer, &errorMessage);
```

The tutorial makes a mention of using HLSL, which is also used by most tutorials online, but HLSL doesn't look anything like the *.vs and *.ps files, HLSL looks more like C++ code and has a Main() function.

Are these essentially the same shaders using different languages?
Which one is newer and better to use?

Thanks,

Comment: HLSL is a language, the file can be named the way you want. Both files here contain HLSL code, but the author has created a separate file for a pixel shader (ps) and another one for a vertex shader (vs). There's nothing "newer and better".

Answer (score 0):

HLSL is a language (High-Level Shading Language), you can name an extension of a shader file with whatever you want because at the end of the day all of this code is in text format. But if you name the extension as .hlsl or .HLSL and if you download HLSL plugin for Visual Studio then your code will be highlighted. Also your code will have a syntax, so if you have an error in your code, compiler will tell you the error in your hlsl code.